# What is the meaning of $(">", this)[1]?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In one JS source I have found this construct:

```
$(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(event){
        var textInputs=$(">input[type='text']", $(">", this)[1]);
        for(var i=0; i<textInputs.length; i++){
```

I quite understand whats happening there, but I am not clear about this line:

```
var textInputs=$(">input[type='text']", $(">", this)[1]);
```

Comment: @MelanciaUK: "construct" no `or`.

Comment: `$(">", this)` is invalid, the selector can't just be `>`. If it was `> *`, then the line would be equivalent to `$(this).children().eq(1).children("input[type='text']")`.

Comment: It's a jQuery selector. Does that help you?

Comment: You might want to check the jquery documentation

Comment: That second argument is the _selector context_. [Read more about that here.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)

Comment: I have to revise my comment: `">"` seems to be a valid selector since jQuery 1.8. Now we also know which version Stack Overflow is using (hint: not > 1.8).

Comment: thank you much, I have to look at jQuery, my fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument is the selector, the second argument is the context

```
$('selector', 'context');
```

Selector is restricted in this case and will only match descendants of your context.

This is equivalent of the `find` method:

```
$('context').find('selector');
```

Both will get the same result.

Comment: You should mark one answer as correct for people to know the solution, and voteup the ones that are also correct so people realize that they were helpful too.

Answer (score 2):

The code uses `$(selector, context)`. `$(">", this)` selects children of the `this` object, and `[1]` returns the second child as a raw DOM element. It then passes the returned value (*which can also be an `undefined`* value) to another `$(selector, context)` as context for selecting `input[type=text]` children.

To me the code is not readable and maintainable. It's (*somehow*) equivalent to:

```
$(function() {
    $("form").submit(function(event) {
        $(this).children(":eq(1)")
               .children('input[type="text"]')
               .each(function(index, element) {
                   // ...
               });
    // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like jquery, and it'd be

```
$('dom elements to look for', 'dom context element')
```

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Comment: But since `>` is not a valid element to look for, the whole thing is bogus.

Comment: @Barmar Bogus or not, it "Works Here": http://jsfiddle.net/ehbLv5gb/1/ (although I do not recommend it for reasons previously mentioned; I wonder if/where this CSS-"extension" behavior is discussed)

Comment: @Barmar: `$(">")` by itself is useless, since it's "children of WHAT!?". but `$(">", this)` has context, and is tehrefore "children of whatever $this is".

Comment: It seems that `">"` is valid since jQuery 1.8. It's not valid before.

Comment: Ahh, I was testing in the Javascript console for SO, it uses 1.7.1, so it complained.